# JSF Handle served-side exception in browser with A4J

Tags: java, jsf, ajax4jsf

Can A4J handle a situation in which ajax call to a server ends with an exception? By handle I mean can it for instance present user with a dialog box stating that an exception has occured? The default behaviour of A4J in presence of a server side exception is to just do nothing which is somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can do it with [A4J](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html_single/#RequestErrorsAndSessionExpirationHandling):

add this to your javascript on any page:

```
A4J.AJAX.onError = function(req, status, message){

    window.alert("Custom onError handler "+message);

}
```